# MVC Return a Json with List and Dictionary

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm trying to return the following as JSON

```
List<string>, Dictionary<int, string>
```

When I try to return

```
List<string>
```

everything works great. The issue is the introduction of the `Dictionary`

My controller is hit and it returns but always returns to the error callback in my ajax function.

I don't understand why.

Some real code now!

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPageLoad()
    {
        var dc = new Bll.DataAccess();     
        var urls = dc.GetUrls(1);          //List<string>
        var templates = dc.GetTemplates(); // dictionary
        return Json(new { urls = urls, templates = templates}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the ajax is

```
$.ajax({
        type: type.toUpperCase(),
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            successDelegate(response);
        },
        failure: function (e) {
            failDelegate(e.statusText);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            errorDelegate(e.statusText);
        }
    })
```

I don't see any error warning other than Internal Server Error but I don't see why. I'm guessing it's something to do with parsing the Dictioanry but I am unable to work out how to fix this

Comment: Do you get a stack trace in the output window? Or in the response (networks tab).

Comment: it's something going wrong in your action method, some exception probably

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, I check the return objects, they look fine. And as I said, if I remove the dictionary it works perfectly :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the key in the dictionary must be of type string or object.

I had `Dictionary<int, string>`

Changing it to `Dictionary<string, int>` resolves the issue